# Make a UIActivityIndicator with background, position centre of the main View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

So What I am aiming for, is a UIActivityIndicator to position in the centre of the screen, with a background around the spinner, and then with a full background at half transparency. This image shows what I am trying to create:

[image]

I have no issues with the spinner etc, but getting the layers all positioned correctly. They all seem to sit below the centre. Please see the image below of what is actually happening:

[image]

The code is below:

```
var spinningActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    let container: UIView = UIView()
    container.frame = self.view.frame
    container.center = self.view.center
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0/360, saturation: 0/100, brightness: 0/100, alpha: 0.4)

    let loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
    loadingView.center = self.view.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 359/360, saturation: 67/100, brightness: 71/100, alpha: 1)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 40

    spinningActivityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    spinningActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    spinningActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    spinningActivityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, loadingView.frame.size.height / 2)
    loadingView.addSubview(spinningActivityIndicator)
    container.addSubview(loadingView)
    view.addSubview(container)
    spinningActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you don't understand the difference between frame and bounds. This line `loadingView.center = self.view.center` is always the wrong kind of thing to say, because those values are in two different coordinate systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding it your view you can add it directly to application window. If you use window, your container can cover entire screen. Can you try this out?

```
var spinningActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
let container: UIView = UIView()
container.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
container.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0/360, saturation: 0/100, brightness: 0/100, alpha: 0.4)

let loadingView: UIView = UIView()
loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
loadingView.center = container.center
loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 359/360, saturation: 67/100, brightness: 71/100, alpha: 1)
loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 40

spinningActivityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
spinningActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
spinningActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
spinningActivityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, loadingView.frame.size.height / 2)
loadingView.addSubview(spinningActivityIndicator)
container.addSubview(loadingView)
window.addSubview(container)
spinningActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

And for stopping indicator and removing view use

```
spinningActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
container.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed! Thanks - The only change needed was on the line `loadingView.center = self.container.center` - it only needed to be `= container.center` . If you update the answer i'll mark it correct for you :)

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is *always* wrong:

```
loadingView.center = self.view.center
```

The reason is that `center` is reckoned in terms of the view's superview's coordinate system. Since these two views are themselves to be subview and superview of one another, the two `center` values are in *two different coordinate systems*. Thus, trying to set them equal to one another can never get you the result you want.

Instead, understand the difference between frame and bounds. The `frame` (and `center`) of the subview is given in terms of the `bounds` of its superview. Thus, the way to center a view within its superview is to put its `center` at the point

```
CGPointMake(
    CGRectGetMidX(theSuperview.bounds),
    CGRectGetMidY(theSuperview.bounds))
```

So, decide what view you want your activity indicator to be at the center of, make your activity indicator that view's subview, and set its `center` in accordance with that formula, and you'll be spot on.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a cleaner answer (**Swift 4**)

```
        self.activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

        self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.activityIndicatorView.style = .whiteLarge
        self.activityIndicatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray.withAlphaComponent(0.75)

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView)

        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
```